# Sudden decline in "Pages crawled per day" in WMT

Tags: seo

Traffic is steady, the site is up, no server issues but since a few weeks I noticed a steady decline in my pages crawled per day. Is this a reason to be worried and how can I figure out why ? This is a big site 1000+ pages. I do minor updates on the site from time to time so all the information is current.

[site http://kaniamea.com/stat.jpg](http://kaniamea.com/stat.jpg)

I have another smaller site and it hasn't done updates for ages and the stats are the opposite there. See graph.

[site http://kaniamea.com/stat2.jpg](http://kaniamea.com/stat2.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try not to change any titles or Meta title related stuff. If the minor changes belongs to plugin updates then go ahead, but frequent changes are not recommend. IF you posted any new article avoid keyword stuffing into the article.